# spout sends tuples just to a subset of bolt instances

Tags: apache-storm

I'm just starting with storm. I have a simple topology of a spout (1 executor) and a bolt (4 executors). The spout and the bolt are connected via "shuffleGrouping".

From what I can see the spout sends tuples only to a subset of bolt executors - the ones that are running on the same host as the spout.

Is this expected? Is there a way to spread the load across all bolt executors no matter where they run?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's expected. I think you can config it by using same spout source, like storm integrate with kafka,then you create 2 topologies, config each spout of each topology with the same topic and same zookeeper host.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up this old post. I had the same problem with a topology and found this post, so I want to share my research, and a/the solution.

I upgraded a topology from Apache Storm 1.0.2 to 2.2.0. Since, the spout sends tuples only to the local bolt executors despite the SHUFFLE grouping mode.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689408/apache-strom-upgrade-from-1-0-3-to-2-2-0-and-not-all-workers-are-used), it's seems expected, but there are a workaround :

```
topology.disable.loadaware.messaging: true
```

See also *org.apache.storm.daemon.GrouperFactory* to understand how this configuration is used.